# Customize RStudio terminal

Tags: rstudio

I use RStudio for diverse projects, and it's useful because it integrates a terminal. But I would like to customize the terminal, for example to give color to the prompt and the root.

I have made such changes on the MacOS terminal, but please, do you know how I can customize that terminal? Any help will be greatly appreciated.